# In ReactJS Can I 'duplicate' the Draggable item so I'm dragging a clone and the original stays in the same place?

Tags: reactjs

I Want to duplicate the draggable item. So when I drag the item it should be stay in the original place. i.e I want to clone that item without remove from its original place.
Please Letting me know if you have any idea about this.[image]

Thanks. Regards
Pankaj